# JS adding text after result

Tags: javascript

I have this code that gives an correct output like

[image]

```
document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value = (((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value) - ((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value)).toFixed(0);

document.getElementById('add_calc_lengte').value = (document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value / document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / document.getElementById('add_dikte').value / document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value * 1000000).toFixed(0);
```

But I would like to add `kg`to the weight and `mm`to the length. It works seperat but I can't get it to work both!

When adding `mm` to the length and not changing code for the weight I have this result:

[image]

```
document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value = (((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value) - ((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value)).toFixed(0);

document.getElementById('add_calc_lengte').value = (document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value / document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / document.getElementById('add_dikte').value / document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value * 1000000).toFixed(0) + ' mm';
```

When I change now the code for the weight I have this result

[image]

```
document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value = (((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value) - ((Math.PI * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) * (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value / 2) / 1000) * (document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / 1000) * document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value)).toFixed(0) + ' kg';

document.getElementById('add_calc_lengte').value = (document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value / document.getElementById('add_breedte').value / document.getElementById('add_dikte').value / document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value * 1000000).toFixed(0) + ' mm';
```

Any suggestions? (and explanation)

Comment: If the values in your inputs are not pure numbers, try to convert them into numbers first and then do the calculation. (e.g. `parseFloat(document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value)`)

Comment: or `+ document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value`

Comment: _"Any suggestions?"_ - Don't add the units in the input itself. Add them as text right next to the input or in the "title": **Weight** -> **Weight (kg)**

Comment: It seems that your problem is in the calculation result of the last line, can you give us the values of:
document.getElementById('add_calc_gewicht').value = ?
document.getElementById('add_breedte').value = ?
document.getElementById('add_dikte').value = ?
document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value = ?

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I agree. But still curious what might the issue now :)

Comment: @BinaryMan The code is fine (I think) since the output is correct. Only the issue when adding extra text.

Comment: ok, if you say (y)

Comment: Use CSS to show units in input box `kg`/`mm`,  use input box for values only.

Answer (score 1):

You added text to the numbers, now you can no longer calculate with them, resulting in `NaN`.

If you use `parseInt` (since you require Integers) as follows:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('Weight and Length fields').value, 10)
```

they will be converted into Numbers again fixing your issue.

Comment: We all need a [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) sometimes (and coffee yes)